# Date: Month and Day To Use TH or Not

Tags: numbers, dates

March 15 had never been that cold. It amazed me. Was global warming fake?

March 15th had never been that cold. It amazed me. Was global warming fake?

Which one is correct when writing a short story.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Such questions are largely a matter of style; there is no single convention. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, identify a [style guide](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) congruent with your audience and tastes, and be consistent in its application.

Comment: What Choster said. If you are a serious short-story writer, use  the style guide  of your publisher and stick to it.    I know some of the requisites seem weird, but publishers always have their agenda   and in my experience  will not even take a  look at your offering until you have satisfied their requirements. Voting to close as it seems to be  POB.

Comment: BTW...good luck with your stories.

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree with Choster and Cascabel's comments that this is a matter of style, I want to raise one more possibility.

Strunk and White take the position that dates in dialogue should be spelled out. Since your example is direct reporting of a statement thought to oneself, consider writing, "March fifteenth had never been that cold."